# expandable listview with view recycle?

Tags: android, listview, recycle

I have modified the listview so that it's height = height of all its children and have put it a scrollview... I am putting images in the list; problems start to arise when adding a lot of images in the list; as the height is now = height of all its children, it seems that the listview is nomore recycling its views but displaying all of them at once causing outofmemory error.

Does anyone have a solution for this? i still want my expandable listview but i also want it to recycle its views (only "display"/render the views that are visible in the scrollview)

Comment: Well, what did you intend to accomplish by wrapping the `ListView` in a `ScrollView`? If it's to have some other content at the top or bottom scroll along in the same container, consider adding those views as header/footer. Alternatively, CommonsWare's `MergeAdapter` should allow you to merge any view anywhere with one or more list contents.

Comment: i have dynamic content, then i have a gallery/gridview or listview of images below the content.. the content have variable length so it may need scrolling

Comment: i ended up displaying the lisview in a dialog... looks more ugly but much more efficient and no outofmemory error